# javascript / css fade out

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys not sure if this is java script or CSS but i got a picture inside a box and when the user hover over it it will change colour(Got 4 of these). My question is how do i get it so when the user dose hover over a box everything else fades out.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="eng" lang="eng">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.meh1
{
    height: 200px; /*Specify Height*/
    width:  200px; /*Specify Width*/
    border: 3px solid blue; /*Add 1px solid border, use any color you want*/
    text-align:center; /*Align the text to the center*/
}

.meh1:hover
{
    border: 3px solid orange;
}   

.meh2
{
    height: 200px; /*Specify Height*/
    width:  200px; /*Specify Width*/
    border: 3px solid blue; /*Add 1px solid border, use any color you want*/
    text-align:center; /*Align the text to the center*/
}

.meh2:hover
{
    border: 3px solid orange;
}



</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $mehs = $('.meh');
$mehs.hover(function(){
$mehs.not(this).fadeTo(200, 0.25);
}, function(){
$mehs.fadeTo(200, 1);
});
 </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="meh">

    <div class="meh1">
        <img src="cw3.jpg" alt="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="meh2">
        <img src="cw2.jpg" alt="Name">
    </div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.meh:hover { format c: }` will make everything dissapear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's javascript... The easiest method is using jQuery. (which, by your other questions, I see you are familiar with).

Assuming all div's have the class `meh`:

```
var $mehs = $('.meh');
$mehs.hover(function(){
  $mehs.not(this).fadeTo(200, 0.25);
}, function(){
  $mehs.fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

I've used `fadeTo()`, as this will maintain your layout (`fadeOut()` will set the element to `display:none;` and affect your page layout)

Comment: So this will work if i have 4 boxes and 1 will appear while others sort of fade out but not completely.

Comment: @AliBOOM, yes. With a 200ms duration, the other boxes will fade to 25% opacity.

Comment: ah ok i see i must set all divs to meh class first for it 2 work

Comment: You can either add them all in the first selection. `var $mehs = $('.meh, .meh2, ...etc')` or give them all a generic class, and another class if they really need different styling.

Comment: ye i tried that var $mehs = $('.meh1, .meh2'); but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".meh").on('mouseover', function(){
        $("Whatever it is that you want to fade").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: i have got 4 boxes, so will this mkae 1 appear and the rest sort of faded out

Comment: Also this makes everything fade out and dosent come back in

Comment: Yeah, if you want that functionality then I think what @ahren has is better for this.